# Trouble backing up my Mac (with Time Machine) to my WD passport

Tags: backup, external-disk, leopard

I just bought a 1 TB WD passport (external hard drive) to backup my Mac. I'm currently operating on a Mac OS x 10.5.8 (Leopard) with a 2GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor.

To format the drive I

- erased the contents of the drive with Disk Utility and formated it as Mac OS X extended (journaled)
- set the volume scheme to one partition, formatted again under Mac OS X (journaled) with GPT

After enabling Time Machine the backup always stops at 52.9 of a 168 GB backup. When I click to continue the backup, Time Machine ostensibly keeps backing up but then again arbitrarily shuts down with no additional information copied to the drive beyond the 52.9Gb.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong, or can anyone suggest anything that might work?

Comment: It could be a corrupted file on the internal HD. Have you tried repairing permissions and verifying the internal HD in Disk Utility?

Comment: Check Console.app (ask Spotlight).  There should be a message telling you what happened.